# How can i use puppet to install network tool like iptraf

Tags: puppet

i am using the example of [iptraf on github](https://github.com/duritong/puppet-iptraf.git)

I do a git clone, and then sudo puppet apply init.pp

but i dont see iptraf installed on the ubuntu 11.04 host

now this puppet is a client ONLY instance, and NO Master.

from another example i see i can install apache2 as:

```
    class basic_services {

      ##Get Apache
      package { 'apache2':
        ensure => 'installed',
      }

      ##Edit the Apache Conf
      file { "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default":
          require => Package["apache2"],
          owner => "root",
          group => "root",
          content => "$some_variables::apache_config",
      }

      ##Make sure Apache is running, and restarts on changes to conf
      service {'apache2':
        require => Package["apache2"],
        ensure => running,
        subscribe => File["/etc/apache2/sites-available/default"],
      }
}
```

so for iptraf:

```
init.pp
class iptraf {
  include iptraf::base
}


base.pp


class iptraf::base {
  package{'iptraf': ensure => installed }  
}
```

I will use this example as a base to develop a manifest for Testing Tools

So what am i missing here , as after i run :

sudo puppet apply init.pp , and try to access iptraf, i get the message:

```
iptraf
The program 'iptraf' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install iptraf
```

Answer (score 0):

move the iptraf directory to the modules. Your directory structure should be this :

/etc/puppet/modules/iptraf/manifests/{init.pp,base.pp}

then do,

sudo puppet apply -e 'include iptraf'

that should install iptraf.

sudo iptraf should open a nice screen in your terminal :)

Comment: still having issues after following your directions:
puppet apply -e 'include iptraf' 
Error: Could not find class iptraf for autobot.cod.ad on node autobot.cod.ad
Error: Could not find class iptraf for autobot.cod.ad on node autobot.cod.ad

Comment: The way you did is okay, but not structured according to puppet standards... See my edits. I should have put the manifests in the directory structure...

    /etc/puppet/modules/iptraf/manifests/init.pp
    /etc/puppet/modules/iptraf/manifests/base.pp


Accept the answer if it works...

Answer (score 0):

in the directory:
/etc/puppet/modules/iptraf
- create a file:
iptraf.pp 
- with contents:

package { "iptraf":
    ensure => "installed"
}
- issue the command:

puppet apply iptraf.pp 
/Stage[main]//Package[iptraf]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
Finished catalog run in 2.71 seconds

run iptraf on command line , the UI POPS UP.
Done!